# demographics of paying mobile gamer

Tags: mobile, monetization, business, demographics

I was googling for this now for a while but didn't find any relevant data.

Does someone know any statistics of the demographics of mobile gamers that actually spend money on their games? It's clear that this data may vary over different genres but any kind of analysis in this direction would be interesting for me.

Comment: This article should be of interest: http://venturebeat.com/2014/02/26/only-0-15-of-mobile-gamers-account-for-50-percent-of-all-in-game-revenue-exclusive/

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about payers for mobile games, you're talking about whales, who represent the majority of the revenue.

Though it varies from game to game, a report from analytics firm Swrve found that only  1.5% of players spent money on mobile games.

Within that 1.5% the revenue follows a power law, with most of the money coming from big spenders - with the aforementioned report stating that 50% of the revenue came from the top 10% of those who spent any money.

Some effort has been put to identify what makes whales tick. Here are some links:

- [Free-to-play whales more rational than assumed](http://www.gamesindustry.biz/articles/2014-04-01-free-to-play-whales-more-rational-than-assumed)
- [Two-thirds of whales are males](http://www.gamesindustry.biz/articles/2013-08-22-two-thirds-of-whales-are-males)
- [Who Are the 'Whales' Driving Free-to-Play Gaming?](http://kotaku.com/who-are-the-whales-driving-free-to-play-gaming-youd-1197333118)

Comment: Do you have anything on the actual spending curve? The definition of "Whales" as the top 5% of spenders does not neccessarily mean they "Represent the majority of the revenue". Though you may well be correct I'd still like to see the numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your links, Sergio, but please note that [link-only answers are discouraged on stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Please try to sumarize the relevant parts of these articles in your own words.

Comment: @Dave Actual charts vary from game to game, but revenue follows a [Power Law](http://www.gamesbrief.com/2010/08/whales-power-laws-and-the-future-of-media/), with most of the money coming from a few big spenders. Gamesbrief has some coverage about it. 

The analytics firm Swrve released a report stating that [50% of the revenue came from the top 10% spenders](http://recode.net/2014/02/26/a-long-tail-of-whales-half-of-mobile-games-money-comes-from-0-15-percent-of-players/) (and that only 1.5% spend, on average)

Comment: Cheers, I've been having a bit of face-palm day with internet reporting and it's refreshing to see some actual figures.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://blog.apptopia.com/game-demographics-that-every-developer-should-know/) with little effort and [this](http://www.theesa.com/facts/gameplayer.asp) was the second google entry. I only know that people with iOS devices and/or Macs are more likely to spend money to purchase your game, to do in-app purchases, or to click on any publicity included in your app i.e.(don't bother with android or Windows Phone) although PCs are popular gaming machines you asked for mobile games.

Comment: thank you for your reply - I found these links before but unfortunately they show demographics of players only in general, not the part of players who are actually playing. I think in mobile games there are two quite distinct groups - those who will not pay anything for games by principle, and those who are willing to spend a buck if it's worth it.

Comment: well as I said: in general iOS users are willing to spend more in games, in-app purchases or more likely to click in publicity. That's would be more like "systemgraphic" rather than demographic but it is still usefull, since iOS users are, in general, younger or have children who play games and purchase that stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your links, but please note that [link-only answers are discouraged on stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Please try to sumarize the relevant parts of these articles in your own words.